# Is there any way to stop overwriting the json file?

Tags: javascript, json, object

actually this code works as expected but, if I do input a different userId, it still do overwrite the existing user (not the file) and the ideia was to add another one

```
 const user = userId;
 const userObj = {[user]:valueX};
    words.users = userObj;
    fs.writeFileSync('words.json', JSON.stringify(words,null,2), finished);
```

input comes from here (readline-sync)

```
let userId = input.question('Enter yourUserId: ');
```

and yes i'm reading the file first

```
let words = JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync('words.json'));
```

Comment: you have to merge the `userObj`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ```
> const userObj = {[user]:valueX};
> words.users = userObj;
> ```

The object you assign to `words.users` needs to include all the existing users and not **just** your new one.

```
const userObj = {...words.users, [user]:valueX };
```

Answer (score 0):

From your code it looks like words.users is an object and in that case

```
if(!words.users) words.users = {};  // Make sure the words users are created
words.users[user] = valueX;
```

This would give you an words.users object that look like this

```
{user1: valueX1, user2: valueX2}
```

And you could access like this

```
console.log(words.users[user1]); // valueX1
```